# Обработка ссылок

Tags: android

Имеется приложение, переделанный браузер. В файле  MainActivity

Имеется код:

```
package com.example.android.myapplicationbrowser;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ProgressBar progressBar;
EditText inputUrl;
WebView webView;
ImageButton sendButton, forwardButton, backButton, refreshButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    inputUrl = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView);
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    sendButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.sendButton);
    forwardButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.forwardButton);
    backButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.backButton);
    refreshButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.refreshButton);

    webView.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());

    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {
            progressBar.setProgress(newProgress);
            if(newProgress==100)
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            else
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });

    WebSettings webset = webView.getSettings();
    webset.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    webView.loadUrl("http://online-prava.ru/????????????.php");

    sendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String url = inputUrl.getText().toString();

            if (!url.startsWith("http://")) {
                url = "http://" + url;
            }

            webView.loadUrl(url);

            InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager)         
getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(webView.getWindowToken(), 0);
        }
    });

    forwardButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (webView.canGoForward())
                webView.goForward();
        }
    });

    backButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (webView.canGoBack())
                webView.goBack();
        }
    });

    refreshButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            webView.reload();
        }
    });

}
}
```

Все ссылки открываются в данном приложении и работают хорошо, он мне требуется чтобы 2-3 ссылки открывались, так как им удобно. к пример ссылка на вк открывалась в приложении ВК.

какой код нужно дописать и куда??? (чтоб ссылка открывалась не в этом же приложении а вызывало ВК приложение  или Телефон для звонка)

Comment: Нужно смотреть куда-то в эту сторону - [Deep linking](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking).

Comment: Похожий вопрос на SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46930334/launch-application-from-another-using-a-deeplink